# Android: ZXing integration error - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, zxing

I have an app which was working fine so I kept committing versions in github. The app is using ZXing library for barcode scanning. Now I went back to an older commit and the app doesn't work anymore. The scanning is crashing with below error. Also here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newpc.qrcode"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'com.guardtime', name: 'ksi-api', version: '4.5.71'
    compile group: 'com.guardtime', name: 'ksi-service-client-simple-http', version: '4.5.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Below error log

```
04-10 15:35:41.752 11352-11352/com.example.newpc.qrcode E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.newpc.qrcode, PID: 11352
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newpc.qrcode/com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:421)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2175)
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.initializeContent(CaptureActivity.java:35)
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:22)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:421) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2175) 
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.initializeContent(CaptureActivity.java:35) 
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:22) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no a com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView on provided layout with the id "zxing_barcode_surface".
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView.initialize(CompoundBarcodeView.java:95)
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView.<init>(CompoundBarcodeView.java:68)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:421) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2175) 
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.initializeContent(CaptureActivity.java:35) 
                                                                              at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:22) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: "The app is using ZXing library for barcode scanning" -- there is no reference to any library in the `build.gradle` that you have in your question.

Comment: I do, please see above, mistakenly put it inside the error code